# ogr2ogr: projection issue when converting a GeoJson to a Shapefile

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, epsg

I want to convert a GeoJSON into a shapefile with the `ogr2ogr` command using the [Spyder](https://www.spyder-ide.org/) Python interpreter.

```
args = ['ogr2ogr', '-f', 'ESRI Shapefile', SHP_FILENAME, GEOJSON_FILENAME]
```

The output shapefile hasn't the same projection as the entry GeoJSON, the `.prj` file has `WGS84` coordinate system by default.

The GeoJSON file is structured as :

```
geojson = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::2154" } },
"features": [
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry" : {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [],
        },
    "properties" :{"ID":ID,"longitude":longitude,"latitude":latitude},
} ]
```

I'm using GDAL 2.2.2 installed with Anaconda for Python 2.7.14.

How to resolve this problem ?

Knowing that on a colleague's computer, the script works perfectly but with GDAL 2.2.4.

Is it related ?

Comment: Try `['ogr2ogr', '-f', 'ESRI Shapefile', '-t_srs', 'EPSG:2154', '-s_srs', 'EPSG:2154', NOM_FICHIER_SHP, NOM_FICHIER_GEOJSON]` to enforce projection input & ouput to ignore issues related to GDAL version with implicit reprojection as GeoJSON should always use WGS84/EPSG:4326. If custom projection, you are on your own. Please, don't ask on this forum in French as rules are about asking questions in English. You may ask questions on French forum Georezo http://georezo.net instead if you want questions and answers in French. PS: French guy here but need to mention forum rules

Comment: I tried the command line. No error messages but the conversion has failed, I do not have the output SHP files.  Am I missing any EPSG code libraries?

Comment: What does ogrinfo print for you? With option `--debug on` you can see more details.

Comment: ogrinfo --debug
ERROR 1: --debug option given without debug level.

Comment: ogrinfo
Usage: ogrinfo [--help-general] [-ro] [-q] [-where restricted_where|@filename]
 [-spat xmin ymin xmax ymax] [-geomfield field] [-fid fid]
         [-sql statement|@filename] [-dialect sql_dialect] [-al] [-rl] [-so] [-fields={YES/NO}]
               [-geom={YES/NO/SUMMARY}] [-formats] [[-oo NAME=VALUE] ...]
               [-nomd] [-listmdd] [-mdd domain|`all`]*     [-nocount] [-noextent]
               datasource_name [layer [layer ...]]

Comment: Try outside Spyder to run the same command using command line shell. Your issue is related to ogr2ogr utility. The command you provided us is a wrapper on the top
`ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -t_srs "EPSG:2154" -s_srs "EPSG:2154" out.shp in.shp`

Comment: The sheel Anaconda Prompt?

Comment: Yes, the "Anaconda Prompt" (I suppose you are on Windows?!)

Comment: OK but I am a error : > ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -t_srs "EPSG:2154" -s_srs "EPSG:2154" 85023_01_170221.shp temp.geojsomm
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `temp.geojsomm' with the following drivers.
  -> `PCIDSK' ...... and a list of drivers

Comment: Do you have file `temp.geojsomm`? And option `--debug on` must be added to otherwise complete ogrinfo command: `ogrinfo your.geojson -al -so --debug on`.

Comment: Rename your file to change extension from `temp.geojsomm` to `temp.geojson` supposing you are in the right folder and the file really exists. Otherwise, GDAL can't guess the format of the datasource input e.g GeoJSON in this case and throw the error you see.

Comment: ThomasG77, 
Indeed I was not in the right folder, I made a cd to the folder containing the GeoJson and the scrpit works via Anaconda Prompt. I have my SHP files with the correct projection

Comment: therefore GDAL is well installed. How do I get Spyder to use Gdal's ogr2ogr feature?